# Copy core data database between two iphone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, synchronization, bonjour

I'm coding an app with core data. I need to sync the database between two iphones running the same app maybe via bonjour...
Can anyone help?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) for the basic network communication. Now you can either

- copy your sqlite file if used in CoreData

or

- use some exchange-format (xml, [json](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)) on top of the server communication.

I myself would consider idea one being quite bad in most situations, also it might fit for your use-case.

With idea two you will have more work but more control about the data representation on each phone.

Actually we are using idea two in my company. But I can't post any code here.